# rollup "unresolved dependencies" and "missing global variable name" errors, but no specific dependencies referenced

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, rollupjs

I'm trying to integrate React into an existing app that used Rollup, and trying to upgrade to the latest Babel and Rollup versions in the process. When I `yarn build`, the error/warning output about unresolved dependencies and missing global variable names doesn't provide any more information about which dependencies are part of the problem:

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
[object Object] (imported by commonjs-proxy:[object Object])
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
[object Object] (guessing '_object_Object_')
created public/app.js in 12.1s
✨  Done in 13.52s.
```

So, in the generated app.js, it's starting and ending with

```
(function (_object_Object_) {
    'use strict';

    var _object_Object___default = 'default' in _object_Object_ ? _object_Object_['default'] : _object_Object_;
    // etc etc etc
}(_object_Object_));
```

This is my rollup.config.js:

```
/**
 * Imports
 */
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify-es';
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json'
import eslint from 'rollup-plugin-eslint';
import filesize from 'rollup-plugin-filesize';
import progress from 'rollup-plugin-progress'
import visualizer from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';


/**
 * Constants
 */
const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

/**
 * Configuration
 */
export default {
  input: 'client/src/main.jsx',
  output: {
    file: 'public/app.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    progress(),
    eslint(),
    resolve({
      mainFields: ['main', 'module', 'browser'],
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    }), // resolve dependencies from node_modules
    json(),
    commonjs({
      include: ['node_modules/**'],
      exclude: ['node_modules/process-es6/**'],
      namedExports: {
        'node_modules/react/index.js': [
          'Children',
          'Component',
          'PropTypes',
          'createElement',
        ],
        'node_modules/react-dom/index.js': ['render'],
      },
    }), // convert CommonJS modules to ES modules
    babel({
      exclude: ['node_modules/**'],
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
    }), // convert with Babel
    production && uglify(), // minify if not development
    !production && visualizer(),
    filesize(),
  ],
};
```

And these are my `devDependencies` from the `package.json`:

```
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015-rollup": "^3.0.0",
    "codacy-coverage": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
    "event-emitter": "^0.3.5",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "1.22.0",
    "mocha-multi-reporters": "^1.1.6",
    "nyc": "^14.1.1",
    "rollup": "^1.27.12",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.3.3",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.2.6",
    "rollup-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-filesize": "5.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-json": "^4.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-progress": "^1.1.1",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify-es": "^0.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-visualizer": "^3.3.0"
```

I've currently got my entry point (`client/src/main.jsx`) and app component stripped down to the bare minimum:

```
import React from 'react'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

const reactContainer = document.querySelector('#reactRoot');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, reactContainer);
```

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() { // eslint-disable-line class-methods-use-this
    return <h1>Here goes.</h1>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

What am I missing here? I've followed that link in the output (https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency) and followed directions pretty meticulously, and also inspected various other Rollup+React repos, but none that I've found use the latest versions of Babel or Rollup.

Comment: Wow, no answers to this question. That's too bad. Did you ever find the solution? (For those web searching for "Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules" and arriving here looking for an answer. This was the 2nd hit in DuckDuckGo.)

Comment: @TylerRick I can't even remember how/if this got resolved at the moment, but I'll check back in if I can track that down.

Comment: I had this exact error message after updating `rollup` version. I had to update `rollup-plugin-commonjs` package too to resolve.

Comment: I tried setting output.globals to an array of strings, but it didn't like that very much and it didn't change the message.